# CSS :nth-child Equation

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an unordered list and each `li` makes up one item in a two column layout:

```
col1    col2
1       2
3       4
5       6
7       8
9       10
11      12
```

I need to have an alternating background colour for each item BUT NOT so each item in one column is the same.

So :

1,4,5,8,9,11 will have one colour; and
2,3,6,7,10,12 will have another colour.

Can this be achieved with one :nth-child rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! After some head scratching:

First, set a standard background colour, then use 4n+4 (every fourth item starting from 4th item = 4,8,12 etc) and also 4n+1 (every fourth item starting from 1 = 1,5,9 etc).

```
li {background:#fff;}
li:nth-child(4n+4), li:nth-child(4n+1) {background:#ccc;}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 rules, one alternating for the first column, the other alternating for the second column.  Reverse the colors for each column, so you have something like:

```
col1     col2
a        b
b        a
a        b
b        a
a        b
b        a
```

Try this:

```
tr.left:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr.left:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
tr.right:nth-child(even) {background: #FFF}
tr.right:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC}
```

Where the rows in the left column have the class `left` and the rows in the right column have the class `right`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ":even" and ":odd" type to get this thing.

```
$('ul li:even').css('background-color','color');

$('ul li:odd').css('background-color','color');
```

You can only nth-child for one "li". Please try above.

Comment: Wouldn't this just result in the columns being 2 different colours?  I need alternating background colours as described above.

Comment: It would result in each row having an alternating color.  Assuming you reversed the 11 and 12 accidentally in your example, my solution does what you need.

Comment: Ah true, but I was hoping for a css only solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your statement about `:nth-child()` is inaccurate. It supports `odd` and `even` but only under each `ul`, not one `li`.